# How to deploy a Sping Restfull api on Azure

Tags: azure, spring-boot

I'm stuck trying to deploy my restfull app I have developped with Spring. It is working on localhost, giving me the expected result when questionning my differents routes I have made with @RequestMapping(/xxx) using cUrl.

Now I would like to try to deploy it to azure so I would be able to cUrl it but with the azure's url (is that clear?).

I have tried these methods:

1. Directly via the eclipse azure plugin (see below)
2. Using the Azure app Service for container : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/java/spring-framework/deploy-spring-boot-java-app-on-linux
3. By deploying a JAR : https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/azure/java/spring-framework/deploy-spring-boot-java-app-with-maven-plugin
4. Some others tricks that I have found on the web

But I m always stuck on this page and the app is not responding to my cUrls calls. Any idea on what I may be doing wrong?
[image]

The eclipse plugin:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

If this is a Spring Boot application with embedded Tomcat in the JAR, use the Java SE Image available on App Services.

[image]

Re-name the JAR file to app.jar

Then, upload it to the WebApp (you can use FTP for simplicity). Place the JAR file to /home/site/wwwroot path.

You can also provide a startup command (Check Configurations blade -> General Settings):

```
java -jar /home/site/wwwroot/app.jar
```

If you are using .war package, try using wardeploy API:

https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Deploying-WAR-files-using-wardeploy